# How can the audio data being sent to the speakers be captured from an application?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

Is there an API that is suitable for doing this? A possible application of this is for writing a visualiser, and to play with real time signal processing.

EDIT: The operating system in question is Windows. On Linux, a roundabout way to accomplish this is with Jack, but I'm hoping for a way to read the data in the audio buffer without having to couple apps to Jack.

EDIT: A good answer is found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211484/how-do-i-capture-the-audio-that-is-being-played)

Comment: The operating system is Win32

Comment: OK - I've fixed your tags for you now - you might want to pay attention to this next time you ask a question as you're more likely to get good answers if you provide crucial details such as operating system, etc.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think that enabled me to find a similar previously asked question, where I found a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211484/how-do-i-capture-the-audio-that-is-being-played

Answer (score 0):

If sound board used for playback has recording device/line like "Stereo Mix", "What U Hear", etc., then it is enought to write simple recording application, that is capable to record from a specified recording device/line and record from the "Stereo Mix",...

General case (for "all sound boards") will require to write special driver. Examples of applications with such spesial drivers: Virtual Audio Cable (http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html); Total Recorder (http://www.totalrecorder/com).